# Command line based UPnP / DLNA controller for Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, dlna, upnp

I am looking for a program that allows to stream video from Linux to a UPnP/DLNA renderer.

Must haves:

- Playback can be initiated by the command line (specifying file to play and hostname of renderer)
- Program exits after playback ends (I want to embed it in a script)

Nice-to-haves:

- Playback is controllable (pause, jump back n seconds) from the rendering device or another UPnP/DLNA client

Comment: Raw guess: AFAIR [VLC can be controlled from command-line](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/), and even ships in the repositories. I've never tried what you want to do, so I don't know if that's covered – but should be worth checking :) Oh, PS: [Can I get a stream for DLNA with vlc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21361537/2533433) might be helpful (just pointers, no answer though). More: [DLNA server with playback progress control](http://askubuntu.com/q/601983/68291)